# Create "show all" link in Views pager

Tags: views, paging

I have created a view that displays titles of contents created by authenticated users. I have used pagination to display specified number of items per page. Besides this I want a "show all" link that when clicked displays all contents on single page I have enabled the views pager "more" link but this link redirects back to the same page besides displaying all the remaining contents.

How can I show a "show all" link in my pager?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve this is to create a separate page display for all content on a single page.  Then add a Footer to the title display with a link to the full page display.

Answer (score 1):

The "Include all items option" only works when the "Expose items per page" is checked. The "Expose items per page" creates an HTML form select list that will allow the user to select the number of items to display per page. Checking the "Include all items option" just adds an option to this HTML form select list to view all items but does not add a "View All" link to the pager. The only solutions I've had was to use a custom theme hook for the theme_pager() within my theme's template.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I run on the same problem not long ago ; it's because the **"more" link option only work with blocks**.

Under the advanced panel, there's an option "link display" which is displaying only with views blocks.
There's an issue which is stated as won't fix, but some people still dicuss on it : https://www.drupal.org/node/1427854

In the mean time, you can simply add a "custom" more link in the footer.

Hope that help.
Juda.

Answer (score 0):

A contributed module is available for the same.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_extra_pagers